# R - Concatenate as aggregation function

Tags: r, nlp, concatenation, aggregate

Let's say I have a data frame consisting of sentence IDs and terms like so:

```
data.frame(sid = c(1, 1, 2, 2), text = c("hello", "world", "whats", "up"))
```

How could I aggregate it to get a data frame like so:

```
data.frame(sid = c(1, 2), text = c("hello world", "whats up"))
```

Or better yet, as a list with corresponding indices like so:

```
list("hello world", "whats up")
```

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out. The group_by and summarize functions do the job.

    `library(tidyverse)

    tibble(sid = c(1, 1, 2, 2), text = c("hello", "world", "whats", "up")) %>%
      group_by(sid) %>%
      summarise(token = paste(lemma, collapse = " "))`

Comment: You can post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: You could use `plyr` and `stringr` to do this:

    library(plyr)
    library(stringr)
    bla <- data.frame(sid = c(1, 1, 2, 2), text = c("hello", "world", "whats", "up"))
    ddply(bla, c('sid'), summarise, text = str_c(text, collapse = " "))

The result is

      sid        text
    1   1 hello world
    2   2    whats up